# Log4Net not watching for app.config file modifications

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Let me start out by explaining what my goal here is. I'm trying to allow modifications to my config file to come into effect without having to restart my program/debugging. Now I've attempted to approach this in two ways, the first way was to simply add the following code at the bottom of my Assemblyinfo.cs file

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

Now the logger works as intended, however, when I modify the .config file during debugging the modifications I have made are not used.

My initial assumption was the the app.config file cannot be "watched" while the program is running for whatever reason. So, I decided to attempt to create an external config file and place the Log4Net information there. To do this I moved all of the Log4Net information out of the app.config file and moved it into the file "Log4Net.config" that I created. Then I modified the code inside Assemblyinfo.cs to be the following:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

However, now the logger says it cannot find the config file upon startup. So, here is what I'm asking.

1) If the app.config can indeed be watched for modifications, what am I doing wrong? Why are my modifications not being noticed and implemented while the program is running?

2) If an external config file is necessary, why can the new config file I created not be found by Log4Net?

This is my first question on stackoverflow, I've looked around but couldn't find something that directly addresses my question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: AFAIK, both methods should work. First thing to do when log4net is not behaving as you would expect is to enable log4net's internal logging see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging your application with Visual Studio, you need to modify the  `YourApplication.vshost.exe.config` file in your output folder (that is the one that is active during debugging).

Comment: Stefan' you are right. When debugging with Visual Studio, you need to modify the vshost.exe.config file instead. It worked for me.